# Could Room of Requirement provide one with any book from Hogwarts Library?

Tags: harry-potter

In OotP(Ch18) Harry summons the Room of Requirement variant suitable for (secretive) DADA practice; the Room also provides him with various DADA books as well as equipment

> "**The walls were lined with wooden bookcases** and instead of chairs there were large silk cushions on the floor. A set of shelves at the far end of the room carried a range of instruments such as Sneakoscopes, Secrecy Sensors and a large, cracked Foe-Glass that Harry was sure had hung, the previous year, in the fake Moodys office. “These will be good when we’re practicing Stunning, “ said Ron enthusiastically, prodding one of the cushions with his foot. “**And just look at these books!” said Hermione excitedly, running a finger along the spines of the large leather-bound tomes**. “A Compendium of Common Curses and their Counter-Actions… The Dark Arts Outsmarted… Self-Defensive Spellwork… wow…” She looked around at Harry, her face glowing, and he saw that **the presence of hundreds of books** had finally convinced Hermione that what they were doing was right. “Harry, this is wonderful, there’s everything we need here!” And without further ado she slid ‘Jinxes for the Jinxed’ from its shelf, sank on to the nearest cushion and began to read."

So, my question is, could the Room of Requirement provide ANY book within the walls of Hogwarts? Maybe even the one from the restricted section? How about the one from professors private libraries? It may be even able to act as a search browser if you really *need*  only book with specific content (like books regarding Horcruxes)

Answer (score 10):

The Room of Requirement is not the Room of Want, meaning it only gives entrance and sees to the needs of individuals who have genuine need of the room. You have to genuinely *need* something in order for the Room of Requirement to work for you.

> 'Sometimes it is there, and sometimes it is not, but when it appears, it is always equipped
>   for the seeker’s needs.'
>   <sub>*Order of the Phoenix* - page 343 - Bloomsbury - chapter 18, *Dumbledore's Army*</sub>

Yes, if the user of the Room of Requirement had genuine need of all the items you list, the room would provide it. I don't think the Room of Requirement sneaks around the castle taking books or other items from teachers and whatnot. It has its own way of providing refuge, goods, and materials.

Comment: I'm really trying to think of a _need_ for having it produce Borge's _Book of Sand_.  Or even better, to transform itself into his _Library_.

Answer (score 1):

Interesting question. I think it is made pretty clear, though, that the Room of Requirement only gives out what is put in. The Room of Hidden Things is a great example of this. This room contained the hidden artifacts of hundreds of generations of Hogwarts students. Perhaps the Room of Hidden Things is the source of all those books Hermione finds, just selected by the Room's user (as in a search engine) and sent to the room where Harry and the DA practice in. But that's just my speculation.

So, I would say no to the idea of the Room of Requirement basically stealing items from other Hogwarts rooms, such as the Library. Every item in the DA's room must have already been in the Room, thus explaining why food couldn't have just been transported from the kitchens to the Room of Requirement in the seventh book. Food is one of the five exceptions to Gamp's Law of Elemental Transfiguration (according to Hermione), so the Room couldn't just make some for the students hiding from the Carrows. If it could take some from somewhere else, however, well, that would answer your question. I'm also assuming that, if any past students had placed actual food in the Room, it would have decayed by the time the DA discover it and so the Room wouldn't have given it to them.

I hope this all makes sense!