# Can things created by the Room of Requirement be removed from the Room of Requirement?

Tags: harry-potter

If something is created in the Room of Requirement due to the user's need can it be removed from the Room of Requirement?  And if removed, does it evaporate swiftly or slowly (as with other items conjured out of thin air) or is it permanent?

I don't believe we ever saw this happen in the books.  The only exception that I recall (besides people who went into the Room and then came out) is Ravenclaw's diadem - which wasn't created by the Room, and which, anyway, immediately disintegrated on being taken out of the Room.  (Maybe it was being taken out of the Room that destroyed it, not the fiendfyre, eh?)

Anyway, this question was sparked by this other question here [*Why didn't Harry get all his books from the Room of Requirement?*](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/67285/why-didnt-harry-get-all-his-books-from-the-room-of-requirement)

Comment: Was the D.A. parchment (or roster) written on stationery from the room? Or did someone just bring it along?

Comment: @ThruGog: They signed it at the meeting in the Hog’s Head, so it wasn’t from the Room.

Comment: Why would the stuff generated by the room be any less permanent than stuff generated by other magical means?

Comment: @MishaRosnach - that's right - but stuff conjured out of thin air doesn't last forever, that's known as part of the canon.

Comment: @davidbak I see. Didn't know that was an accepted canon thing. I suppose I would then default to assuming stuff conjured by the room has the same limitation, at least when it leaves its environment. After a while it deteriorates. But obviously I'm just going by assumption, and you're just as capable of doing that as I am :) No reference or anything.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Well to answer the first part of your question, the broomsticks the trio use to evacuate themselves, Malfoy and Goyle from the room certainly do make it out of the room:

> Then, through the smoke, Harry saw a rectangular patch on the wall and steered the broom at it, and moments later clean air filled his lungs and they collided with the wall in the corridor beyond.
>
> Malfoy fell off the broom and lay face down, gasping, coughing and retching.
>
> <sub>*Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows* - p.509 - Bloomsbury - Chapter 31, *The Battle of Hogwarts*</sub>

So, yes, they were able to be removed.

Whether they faded away with time is not possible to say.

Also, given the nature of the room of hidden things, it is not clear whether the brooms were created by the room itself, or whether they were once hidden there by students, who brought them into the room from outside. One presumes the magic of the room brought the brooms to hand, in this case, but there's no absolute proof the room created them.

I'll go you a little bit better than that. When Dobby first recommended the Room of Requirement to Harry he said:

> '... and Dobby knows Mr Filch has found extra cleaning materials there when he has run short, sir, and -'
>
> <sub>*Harry Potter and the Order of the Phoenix* - p.343 - Bloomsbury - Chapter 18, *Dumbledore's Army*</sub>

I think it fair to conclude that the cleaning materials were generated by the room itself. The room of hidden things is a little different as it's basically a storage vault, whereas the rest of the time the Room seems to equip itself. It also seems very likely Filch was able to take those materials out, otherwise it's hardly much of a recommendation from Dobby is it? How long these materials survived, though, is again unclear.

That's the best I can do.

Comment: If a cleaning material disappears after it's been used to clean the floor… does the floor become dirty again? </bizarre conundrums>

Comment: Well.  I forgot about the cleaning materials.  I'd have to say that was evidence stuff could be taken out and would last at least a little while.  And, @JanusBahsJacquet, it's best not to think about such things.  But I thought it was clear that all the junk in the room, including old, confiscated brooms, were from outside the room, brought in there by students, teachers, or house elves.  IMO.

Comment: Yeah, the broomsticks were left there by students.  If the Room had made them, they'd have been newer and in better condition.

Comment: @HarryJohnston [Citation needed]. The room of hidden things is a room full of junk, really, tatty, dirty mess, amongst which the user's contraband can be hidden. This is exactly the sort of thing I can see the room of requirement conjuring up. There's a very strong implication that the room's mess has been added to and augmented by its users, but some of the mess could have been pre-generated. Innocuous tatty broomsticks for example.

Comment: Again, it's clear from the fact things seem to have died and congealed that things placed in the room of hidden things at any point age. This presumably goes for any pre-generated junk that comes with room. So who's to say those three broomsticks weren't generated by the room and weren't once new?

Comment: I meant "if the Room had made them *on the spot, in response to Harry's need* they'd have been newer".  For the record, though I don't think it matters, I also disagree that the Room of Hidden Things necessarily started out already full; anything placed there is hidden by definition simply because so few people know about the Room.  (In early times, it's entirely possible that *nobody* knew about it, and it was only ever discovered by accident when it was needed.  "Huh, I've never noticed that cupboard before.  Lucky I spotted it now, really, when I needed somewhere to hide this.")

Comment: I don't necessarily know that it started out full but I doubt it started out empty. If all of the junk in there was generated by users then it's been used a lot, so the first few people to use it would hardly have had their stuff well-hidden. It also tends to go the extra mile to make a room that is itself well-equipped for its seekers needs when you get inside. Like filling the DA room with books and cushions and all the rest. As for new broomsticks, you say that, but it might be beyond the room's capabilities to generate shiny new stuff, which is out of keeping with the room they were in

Comment: @Au101 interesting interpretation